# Field update on parent object based on child criteria

Tags: validation, childrelationship

I have a custom child object called Job on Account. They are in lookup relationship.
The field on Account is HasOpenJob, I want that to automatically change to True, in case any of its Job's Stage field is Open and change to False, in case there is no Job wit Open stage is associated.
What should be the best solution for that? I am not so good in triggers :(
Thanks a lot

Comment: [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries).

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a workflow rule on Job on Account object(child object) and under that workflow rule you can define a workflow action which is 'Update Field' in order to update the field on your parent object.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MNniIAG

You can follow the steps in the documentation above to get your work done. And also you can use a process builder as well. But according to the given scenario in your question, I think you can easily get your work done by using a workflow rule.

Comment: Thanks Ruklani for the answer. I am afraid that this would not solve my problem, because for example there are 3 jobs under one account. If the 1st and 2nd jobs are Open and I close the 3rd job, it changes the HasOpenJob to closed, because it evaluate only the one, which was changed  :(

Comment: In that case I think process builder is the best for you. @Lilla Szekely